# Without exposing the interface in the public header of framework can I pass a custom object to the client application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, oop

I am working with a objective-C framework.
I have a public framework header "MyPublicHeader.h" exposed to the client application. I have a custom class in the project,

```
//MyCustomClass.h file
@interface MyCustomClass.h
- (NSString *) methodA;
@end

//MyCustomClass.m file
@inplementation
- (NSString *) methodA {
}
@end
```

If I want the client to instantiate the class I have to make it as public framework header. I want to hide the interface as a curiosity, is there any way to do it???

Answer (score 0):

First know that nothing can be truely hidden in Objective-C due to the nature of dynamic dispatch and the features in the runtime which allow discovery of methods etc.

That said there are a number of ways to do this, a couple:

1. Use a subclass. Declare a superclass and publish its interface as part of your framework. Make your class a subclass of this and publish its interface only within the framework. You define one or more `init` methods in the superclass which return and instance of the subclass, and if you want to expose any further API define it in the superclass with dummy (or faulting) implementations and less the subclass override etc. This approach is similar to the model used for classes like `NSString`.
2. A `.h` file is just text and you can exploit this: make two `.h` files, say `MyCustomClass.h` and `InternalMyCustomClass.h`. In the first just declare the interface with no members, or the API you wish to make public, and publish that to users of the framework. In the second declare the real interface used within the framework. You **must** make sure to keep all three of the files (2 `.h`, `.m`) in sync. This approach would be call little naughty by some, "here be dragons" by others, or "needs must" by yet others...

You might also like to look into "class extensions" which are related to *categories*.

Hope that satiates your curiosity a little, and keep up with the curiosity its good (except for cats)!

Answer (score -1):

You could create an empty wrapper class which only holds a reference to your `MyCustomClass` object.

When they create this object you secretly instantiate an object of your `MyCustomClass` inside and extract it when they pass you an object of the wrapper class.

Not sure if this is exactly what you want to achieve, but could be a workaround.

Comment: How can wrapper class can be instantiated in the client application if I don't include it in the public headers?
Sorry, I don't get the idea. Can u explain a bit?

Comment: No problem. You have to expose the wrapper class, of course, but since it's "empty" you don't have to share the implementation of you `MyCustomClass` too. 
You just share a class with an initializer as far as they know. Than you have your object hidden inside of it. 
Hope this helps to make my idea clearer.